# Finding no. of items in the observation, when mean is given?

Tags: statistics, economics

The mean of certain number of observations is 40. If two more items with values 50 and 64 are added to this data, the mean increases to 42. Find the number of items in the original data?

Comment: How to understand "two or more items"? Does the mean stay fixed at $42$ even if I add 10.000 items with value $50$? That sounds quite strange...

Comment: It would improve your Question to include more *context*.  Why is the problem important/interesting/difficult ?  What did you consider in approaching the problem?  Are there similar problems you've seen worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $x$ to be the new number of items. Your grand total now is $42x$ (mean $\times$ number of items). The old total was $40(x-2)$ using the same logic. So you can write:

$42x = 40(x - 2) + 50 + 64$

Rearrange:

$2x = 34$

$x = 17$

So the original number $x - 2 = 15.$